# Can we change "of" by "has" in every sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

> The pain is *of* a degree that calls for morphine.

Can we change *be + of* with *has*?

> The pain *has* a degree that calls for morphine.

I know we can not do that in every sentence with *of* ... then, what is the *rule* here that allows us to make this change in some sentences ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*to be of* and *to have* express two different ideas although in some contexts they may seem similar

- *to have* is a verb describing possession of the subject.
- *to be of* describes a property or origin of the subject.

"Degree" is describing the quality of the pain; we wouldn't think of a degree as something the pain has/possesses.

Thus,

> The pain is of a degree that calls for morphine

would be understood.

> The pain has a degree that calls for morphine

sounds unnatural.

If you want to use "has", you could say:

> The pain has an intensity that calls for morphine

Answer (score -2):

**The pain is of a degree** is not idiomatic. One has to start with a grammatical sentence. An English speaker would say: The X of Y for this structure.

Idiomatically, we would say:
**The degree of (the) pain** calls for morphine.
**The extent of the damage** is sad.
'

Nouns qualifying the intensity of some condition:

The level of [noun]

The intensity of [noun]

The extent of [noun]

The degree of [noun]

The lack of [noun]

This is not a full list, it is merely illustrative of the structure here...

Comment: Not idiomatic doesn't make a sentence ungrammatical. "The degree of this pain calls for morphine" may be more likely, but I'm not actually sure that "is of a degree" would not be understood easily or found in actual English writing. It does have non-zero use in NGrams

Comment: Maybe "of a degree" is not *common*, but it's perfectly understandable and in live usage.  For example, ["Here is a fusion of psychological and social problems which is of a degree that surpasses similarities to the others."](https://books.google.com/books?id=o5G4BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&dq=%22is+of+a+degree%22) or ["...the level of pastiche on display in the movie is of a degree only perhaps matched by ..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=AdFvAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA63&dq=%22is+of+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPhrau05HPAhVFVh4KHSoJAVA4ChDoAQhAMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20of%20a%20degree%22&f=false)

Comment: *of a degree* here is perfectly ok.

Comment: It is not about being understood. The examples you posted are very complex albeit unedited sentences. /The level of pastiche/ + /of a level is REDUNDANT/. It should be; /The level of pastiche in the movie is only matched by/ The standard way to express this is: [adjective] degree of pain calls for. Using NGram as proof of anything linguistic is a fallacy. And /Here is a fusion etc./ also sounds unedited. Of a degree is not wrong in and of itself. Let's not confuse unedited text "found on the Internet (NGram) and what could be said more idiomatically.